# Use of struct timeval to set the response timeout on LibModbus

Tags: c++, modbus, timeval

I am using the library LibModbus to connect with ADAM devices. I had some previous problem sending some commands to the device but setting a bigger response timeout it was fixed, this was in a previous version of the library.

Now, I am using the latest library, where the set_response_timeout uses a timeval struct.
Link to the functions manual in the library:
    [Get_response_timeout](http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_get_response_timeout.html) / [set_response_timeout](http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_set_response_timeout.html)

I am using the library as follows

```
struct timeval response_timeout;
struct timeval old_response_timeout;
modbus_get_response_timeout(mb, &old_response_timeout);
printf("\nold_tv_sec: %d, old_tv_usec: %d\n", old_response_timeout.tv_sec, old_response_timeout.tv_usec);

response_timeout.tv_sec = 60;
response_timeout.tv_usec = 0;
modbus_set_response_timeout(mb, &response_timeout);

modbus_get_response_timeout(mb, &old_response_timeout);
printf("\nnew_tv_sec: %d, new_tv_usec: %d\n", old_response_timeout.tv_sec, old_response_timeout.tv_usec);
```

But if I print the value of the response timeout using get_response_timeout, previously and after setting it, it returns the same values:

- Response of modbus_get_response_timeout(mb, &old_response_timeout) before the setting
  old_tv_sec: 500000, old_tv_usec: 23224832
- Values of the timeval struct to send to  modbus_set_response_timeout(mb, &response_timeout)
  to_set_tv_sec: 60, to_set_tv_usec: 0
- Response of modbus_get_response_timeout(mb, &old_response_timeout) after setting the new values.

  new_tv_sec: 500000, new_tv_usec: 23224832

Comment: Sorry about that, I use the same variable to track the changes on the response_timeout, so I used old_response_timeout for both previous and after functions. Already edited

Comment: What is the return value of `modbus_set_response_timeout`? Oh wait, I guess there is no indication of success or failure in the new API?

Comment: You can see the functions documentation on the links provided. There is no return value to check if failure or not. To do that u have to do the way I am doing, checking if the value has changed using the modbus_get_response_timeout.

Comment: So it appears that 60 seconds is too short, and I think `modbus_set_response_timeout` prevents that.

Comment: Setting it to 9000000 returns the same response:

old_tv_sec: 500000, old_tv_usec: 65

to_set_tv_sec: 90000000, to_set_tv_usec: 0

new_tv_sec: 500000, new_tv_usec: 65

Comment: Interesting. I would contact the GitHub author. I don't see the new code posted there, so I cannot see the problem. One last thing I'd try is to zero out the `timeval` struct before setting anything.